# How to load environment variables in Svelte using Vite or Svite

Tags: environment-variables, svelte, vite, dotenv

I've been trying to figure out best practices on implementing environment variables for API configurations in Svelte App. As far as I know, We have to use either Vite or Svite to make it work. Can anyone help me find a solution please ??

Comment: Did you get an answer/solution specifically for svelte not sveltekit? Facing similar issue with Vite 4/Svelte. With Vite 3.x I was using dotenv and process.env and worked fine. Now, that works locally but not when deployed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I did it but I bet there are other good practices

I make use of [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) and `$lib` provided by [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$lib).

Below are my folder structure and related js:

```
├── sveltekit-project/        // Root
|   ├── src/
|   |   ├── lib/
|   |   |   ├── env.js
|   |   |   ├── other.js
|   |   |   ... 
|   |   |   
|   |   ├── routes/
|   |   |   ├── main.svelte
|   |   |   ...
|   |   ├── app.html
|   |   ...
|   ├── .env
```

```
/** /src/lib/env.js **/
import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()

export const env = process.env
```

```
/** /src/lib/other.js **/
import { env } from '$lib/env'

const secret = env.YOUR_SECRET
```

By the way, I recommend you reading the "How do I use environment variables?" part in [SvelteKit FAQ](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq). It seems very relevant to what you concern, but I am afraid it means some workarounds are needed instead of the `VITE_*` variables..

Comment: Your answer is useful for SvelteKit. But unfortunately I'm seeking solutions for Vanilla Svelte. If you can, help me with this. By the way thanks a lot for the detailed answer.

Comment: Found this, and helped me understand a bit more: https://vadosware.io/post/pattern-for-env-in-sveltekit/

Comment: This seems to have disappeared from the FAQ for some reason

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? Although it might be useful for SvelteKit, the question was for Svelte only.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be some confusion around the security issues, but it's actually quite simple.

**If you want to use insensitive information, proceed like this:**

- create an `.env` and/or `.env.local`, `.env.production` file, read more here https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files
- name your variable `VITE_<some name>` for example `VITE_API_URL` to store where your backend location is. That's not sensitive information so it's ok to expose this through your svelte app to the internet.
- you can then access this directly inside of the script tags in svelte like this: `import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL`

**If you have sensitive information:**

Then you shouldn't expose it in a svelte client... PLEASE don't do something like suggested in Saad's answer and expose your API key to the public! Instead you'll need a server to securely hold that information, but how to setup a server is then again a different topic.

Comment: import.meta.env. works but when running tests with `jest unit` it fails.

Answer (score 1):

## Warning

**The `VITE_` prefix would expose sensitive information to client side! [More info](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files)**

Normally, I'd simply delete this answer, but its clear that the whole `import.meta.env.VITE_SECRET_PASSWORD` is not a clever design.  What is the point of using a .env variable that is not secure, per the security note warning at https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files ??

As a developer, my expectation is that I can use .env variables to store secure information.

Let this answer stand as a warning:  Do not do this.

## My original response below:

I spent some time struggling here..

Environment Variable file, must be named `.env`:

```
VITE_SENDGRID_API_KEY=SG.9999999999....999999999999
```

I spent way too much time to figure out that `sendgrid.env` as a filename will not work.

I added a file to the /src/lib directory called `env.js`.  Here are the complete contents of that file:

```
export const ENV_OBJ = {
    SENDGRID_API_KEY: import.meta.env.VITE_SENDGRID_API_KEY,
    TEST: "test, test, test"
};
```

And then when I need it elsewhere...

```
import { ENV_OBJ } from '$lib/env'
// console.log("API Key.test: ", ENV_OBJ.TEST);
sgMail.setApiKey(ENV_OBJ.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

I'm using SvelteKit, Javascript, etc... No extra dotenv. Keep it simple, make it easy.

Comment: Do not do this. Everything that has the VITE_* prefix may be exposed in the client bundle.

https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files

"Since any variables exposed to your Vite source code will end up in your client bundle, VITE_* variables should not contain any sensitive information."

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kansuler , your comment saved my @ss , I don't know how the f did I miss that security notice in vite docs when I first learnt about env vars. I came here by luck as well while searching how to access env vars in `.svelte` files :)

Comment: Normally I’d delete this answer, but as @a3k has shown, it’s a valuable warning of what not to do.  Perhaps a “Warning, do not do this” edit to my original response might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure all your environment variables start with the prefix "VITE_".

Example:

```
VITE_API_KEY=8465313163463435434353535
```

2. Include your variable in the Svelte file using the syntax "import.meta.env.VARIABLE_NAME".

Example:

```
headers: {
          "X-RapidAPI-Key": import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY
        }
```

And that's it. Hope that helps.